# Laravel 4.2 move pivot data into return model object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database, pivot-table

I have a model returned from the data that looks like this,

```
    {
        "name" : "A test name",
        "data_due" : "2015/01/01",
        "user_id" : 1,
        "viewers": [
            {
                "id": 264,
                "email": "ainley87simon@gmail.com",
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": "",
                "display_name": "",
                "initials": null,
                "active": null,
                "cost_visible": 0,
                "notification_frequency": "H",
                "pivot": {
                    "project_id": 667,
                    "user_id": 264,
                    "involved":1
                }
            }
       ]
 }
```

Ideally that I would be wanting is the following to be returned,

```
        {
        "name" : "A test name",
        "data_due" : "2015/01/01",
        "user_id" : 1,
        "viewers": [
            {
                "id": 264,
                "email": "ainley87simon@gmail.com",
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": "",
                "display_name": "",
                "initials": null,
                "active": null,
                "cost_visible": 0,
                "notification_frequency": "H",
                "involved":1,
                "pivot": {
                    "project_id": 667,
                    "user_id": 264,

                }
            }
       ]
 }
```

Basically what I wanting to do is move the involved columns that is returned in the pivot table into the main object. This is a many to many relationship that looks like this in the Project.php model,

```
public function viewers() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'project_viewer')->withPivot('involved');
}
```

Is there away to return involved as part of each viewer object not in the pivot data?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot get pivot data as the related model field in a query result. 
But after your query there are some options.

**You can define an accessor for the pivot field:**

In your Viewer model:

```
function getInvolvedAttribute() 
{
   return $this->pivot->involved;
}
```

And you can access this, like this way:

```
$user = User::with('viewers')->find(1);
foreach($user->viewers as $viewer) {
   echo $viewer->involved; // Here involved is available
}
```

**The other method is run through on your query result, and add this to your models:**

```
$user = User::with('viewers')->find(1);
foreach($user->viewers as $viewer) {
   $viewer->involved = $viewer->pivot->involved;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution in [Laravel Forums](https://laravel.io/forum/04-18-2014-retrieve-model-using-pivot-table-return-the-model-to-client-as-json-and-include-a-column-from-pivot):

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php
// Project model
// override by aliasing the column to involved,
// preventing it being attached to the pivot model
public function viewers()
{
    $this->belongsToMany('User', 'project_viewer')->withPivot('involved as involved');
}

// User model
// To remove the pivot data in JSON, add this to the User model:
protected $hidden = ['pivot'];

// Execution
$project->viewers->all();
// [
//   {
//     "id": 264,
//     "email": "ainley87simon@gmail.com",
//     "first_name": "",
//     "last_name": "",
//     "display_name": "",
//     "initials": null,
//     "active": null,
//     "cost_visible": 0,
//     "notification_frequency": "H",
//     "involved":1  
//   },
//   ...
// ]
```

I think this solution is much cleaner, removing unnecessary data for most use-cases and making it easier to access pivot attributes only when needed.

Old question, but maybe it'll still help some fellow coders..